# Setup gnome-clock's Timer via cli

Tags: gnome, clock, gnome-clocks

I want to make some automations which includes setup the gnome-clock's Timer via command prompt.
I was looking on the `--help` option, but I didn't find ways to control the application via cli.

Is there a way to do this?